# Regex for fraction mathematical expressions using python re module

Tags: python, regex, fractions

I need a regex to parse through a string that contains fractions and a operation `[+, -, *, or /]` and to return a 5 element tuple containing the numerators, denominators, and operation using the `findall` function in the re module.

Example: `str = "15/9 + -9/5"`

The output should of the form`[("15","9","+","-9","5")]`

I was able to come up with this:

```
pattern = r'-?\d+|\s+\W\s+'

print(re.findall(pattarn,str))
```

Which produces an output of `["15","9"," + ","-9","5"]`. But after fiddling with this for so time, I cannot get this into a 5 element tuple and I cannot match the operation without also matching the white spaces around it.

Comment: Doesn't `[tuple(["15" ,"9", " + ", "-9", "5"])]` yield `[("15", "9", " + ", "-9", "5")]`? Do you also need to get rid of the whitespaces? If so, `[tuple([x.replace(' ', '') for x in ["15", "9", " + ", "-9", "5"]])]` yields ` `[("15", "9", "+", "-9", "5")]`.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will work:

```
(-?\d+)\/(\d+)\s+([+\-*/])\s+(-?\d+)\/(\d+)
#lets walk through it
(-?\d+) #matches any group of digits that may or may not have a `-` sign to group 1
       \/ #escape character to match `/`
         (\d+) #matches any group of digits to group 2
              \s+([+\-*/])\s+ #matches any '+,-,*,/' character and puts only that into group 3 (whitespace is not captured in group)
                              (-?\d+)\/(\d+) #exactly the same as group 1/2 for groups 4/5
```

demo for this:

```
>>> s = "15/9 + -9/5 6/12 * 2/3"
>>> re.findall('(-?\d+)\/(\d+)\s([+\-*/])\s(-?\d+)\/(\d+)',s)
[('15', '9', '+', '-9', '5'), ('6', '12', '*', '2', '3')]
```

Comment: Definitely did the trick! And what a great explanation to go along with it! Thank you, I learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A general way to tokenize a string based on a regexp is this:

```
import re

pattern = "\s*(\d+|[/+*-])"

def tokens(x):
  return [ m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(pattern, x) ]

print tokens("9 / 4 +    6 ")
```

Notes:

- The regex begins with `\s*` to pass over any initial whitespace.
- The part of the regex which matches the token is enclosed in parens to form a capture.
- The different token patterns are in the capture separated by the alternation operation `|`.
- Be careful about using `\W` since that will also match whitespace.